# QGIS with standalone C++ application in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qgis

My projects consists of several subprojects, one of which includes QGIS libraries.

.pro file :

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

CONFIG += ordered

SUBDIRS += \
    Utils \
    Maps \
    GoogleMapsInterface \   
    Positioning \
    NetworkObjects \
    DataBaseManager \
    SensorNetworkUI \
```

This is the .pro file of Maps, that includes the QGIS libraries:

```
CONFIG += c++11
CONFIG += staticlib
TEMPLATE = lib
QT += core gui
QT += widgets
QT += xml

TARGET = maps

DEFINES += MAPS_INTERFACE

INCLUDEPATH += "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/include/"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/OSGeo4W/include/"

win32:CONFIG(Release, Debug|Release) {
 LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/lib/ -lQtCore4
 LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/lib/ -lQtGui4
 LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/lib/ -lQtXml4
}

else:win32:CONFIG(Debug, Debug|Release) {
 PRE_TARGETDEPS += C:/OSGeo4W/lib/QtCored4.lib
 PRE_TARGETDEPS += C:/OSGeo4W/lib/QtGuid4.lib
 PRE_TARGETDEPS += C:/OSGeo4W/lib/QtXmld4.lib
 LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/lib/ -lQtCored4
 LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/lib/ -lQtGuid4
 LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/lib/ -lQtXmld4
}

LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/lib -lgdal_i -lgeos_c
LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-dev/lib -lqgis_core -lqgis_gui

DEFINES += CORE_EXPORT=__declspec(dllexport)
DEFINES += GUI_EXPORT=__declspec(dllexport)
```

This is the .pro file for SensorNetworkUI:

```
CONFIG += console
TARGET = SensorNetwork
TEMPLATE = app

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4):
QT += widgets
QT += core gui
QT += opengl
QT += sql
QT += xml
QT += multimedia

INCLUDEPATH += ../
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/include/"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/OSGeo4W/include/"

win32:CONFIG(Release, Debug|Release) {
 LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/lib/ -lQtCore4
 LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/lib/ -lQtGui4
 LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/lib/ -lQtXml4
}

else:win32:CONFIG(Debug, Debug|Release) {
 PRE_TARGETDEPS += C:/OSGeo4W/lib/QtCored4.lib
 PRE_TARGETDEPS += C:/OSGeo4W/lib/QtGuid4.lib
 PRE_TARGETDEPS += C:/OSGeo4W/lib/QtXmld4.lib
 LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/lib/ -lQtCored4
 LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/lib/ -lQtGuid4
 LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/lib/ -lQtXmld4
}

DEFINES += CORE_EXPORT=__declspec(dllexport)
DEFINES += GUI_EXPORT=__declspec(dllexport)

LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/lib -lgdal_i -lgeos_c
LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-dev/lib -lqgis_core -lqgis_gui
LIBS += -L../ -ldbmanager -lsnobjects -lpositioning -lsnutils -lmaps
```

However, I am getting errors like these:

```
maps.lib(moc_ClickTool.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class QVariant __thiscall QgsExpression::Function::func(class QList<class QVariant> const &,class QgsFeature const *,class QgsExpression *)" (?func@Function@QgsExpression@@UAE?AVQVariant@@ABV?$QList@VQVariant@@@@PBVQgsFeature@@PAV2@@Z)
MainWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class QVariant __thiscall QgsExpression::Function::func(class QList<class QVariant> const &,class QgsFeature const *,class QgsExpression *)" (?func@Function@QgsExpression@@UAE?AVQVariant@@ABV?$QList@VQVariant@@@@PBVQgsFeature@@PAV2@@Z)
```

I also noticed that the auto complete suggestions given by Qt Creator don't include the QGIS header files. Does this mean Qt Creator is not able to find them? It does not throw up errors once the entire name has been typed out. I can even open said header files in Qt Creator.

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

EDIT:
This is where the error begins:

```
Creating library ..\SensorNetwork.lib and object ..\SensorNetwork.exp
maps.lib(moc_ClickTool.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class QVariant __thiscall QgsExpression::Function::func(class QList<class QVariant> const &,class QgsFeature const *,class QgsExpression *)" (?func@Function@QgsExpression@@UAE?AVQVariant@@ABV?$QList@VQVariant@@@@PBVQgsFeature@@PAV2@@Z)
MainWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class QVariant __thiscall QgsExpression::Function::func(class QList<class QVariant> const &,class QgsFeature const *,class QgsExpression *)" (?func@Function@QgsExpression@@UAE?AVQVariant@@ABV?$QList@VQVariant@@@@PBVQgsFeature@@PAV2@@Z)
maps.lib(MapCanvas.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class QVariant __thiscall QgsExpression::Function::func(class QList<class QVariant> const &,class QgsFeature const *,class QgsExpression *)" (?func@Function@QgsExpression@@UAE?AVQVariant@@ABV?$QList@VQVariant@@@@PBVQgsFeature@@PAV2@@Z)
maps.lib(ClickTool.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class QVariant __thiscall QgsExpression::Function::func(class QList<class QVariant> const &,class QgsFeature const *,class QgsExpression *)" (?func@Function@QgsExpression@@UAE?AVQVariant@@ABV?$QList@VQVariant@@@@PBVQgsFeature@@PAV2@@Z)
maps.lib(moc_MapCanvas.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class QVariant __thiscall QgsExpression::Function::func(class QList<class QVariant> const &,class QgsFeature const *,class QgsExpression *)" (?func@Function@QgsExpression@@UAE?AVQVariant@@ABV?$QList@VQVariant@@@@PBVQgsFeature@@PAV2@@Z)
maps.lib(moc_ClickTool.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class QVariant __thiscall QgsExpression::Function::func(class QList<class QVariant> const &,class QgsExpressionContext const *,class QgsExpression *)" (?func@Function@QgsExpression@@UAE?AVQVariant@@ABV?$QList@VQVariant@@@@PBVQgsExpressionContext@@PAV2@@Z)
MainWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class QVariant __thiscall QgsExpression::Function::func(class QList<class QVariant> const &,class QgsExpressionContext const *,class QgsExpression *)" (?func@Function@QgsExpression@@UAE?AVQVariant@@ABV?$QList@VQVariant@@@@PBVQgsExpressionContext@@PAV2@@Z)
maps.lib(MapCanvas.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class QVariant __thiscall QgsExpression::Function::func(class QList<class QVariant> const &,class QgsExpressionContext const *,class QgsExpression *)" (?func@Function@QgsExpression@@UAE?AVQVariant@@ABV?$QList@VQVariant@@@@PBVQgsExpressionContext@@PAV2@@Z)
...
...
maps.lib(MapCanvas.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QgsRasterDataProvider::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QgsRasterDataProvider@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
maps.lib(MapCanvas.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QgsRasterLayer::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QgsRasterLayer@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
maps.lib(ClickTool.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall QgsMapTool::renderComplete(void)" (?renderComplete@QgsMapTool@@UAEXXZ)
maps.lib(ClickTool.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall QgsMapTool::isTransient(void)const " (?isTransient@QgsMapTool@@UBE_NXZ)
maps.lib(ClickTool.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall QgsMapTool::isEditTool(void)const " (?isEditTool@QgsMapTool@@UBE_NXZ)
..\SensorNetwork.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 93 unresolved externals
jom: D:\Atmika\Sensor_Network\build\win32\Debug\SensorNetworkUI\Makefile.Debug [..\SensorNetwork.exe] Error 1120
jom: D:\Atmika\Sensor_Network\build\win32\Debug\SensorNetworkUI\Makefile [debug] Error 2
14:21:50: The process "D:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Sensor_Network (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.1 MSVC2015 32bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error definitely points to the linker not finding the correct symbol in the library, as indicated by "error LNK", so headers were correctly found previously.

1. The core library of QGIS is not found
2. The core library is not linked due to a missing dependency `LIBS += ...` in one of your projects
3. The libraries were compiled with a different compiler than yours, producing an ABI that is not understood by your compiler
4. Your headers and the actual libary differ (for instance if they point to different version QGIS).

You should probably check that the library files you point to are present and corresponds to the right version of QGIS.
If linking dynamically, also make sure that **all** projects depending on it actually include the linker directive `LIBS += ...`.

---

EDIT: The OP found the problem to be simply the dllexport, that should be **dllimport** instead for QGIS CORE_EXPORT and GUI_EXPORT variables:

```
DEFINES += CORE_EXPORT=__declspec(dllimport)
DEFINES += GUI_EXPORT=__declspec(dllimport)
```

A well documented site as reference for QGIS:
https://3nids.wordpress.com/

Comment: Thanks..but how do I check if they are pointing to the right version? I used OSGeo4W to download the qgis libraries and headers.

Comment: I'm download the last version to check but that's unlikely if you all downloaded at once. Version is seen and specified usually directly in the lib name (or with simlinks on linux). Are you getting the error when compiling "SensorNetworkUI" project itself ? Or do you have a more complete build log to help ? By the way for your INCLUDEPATH you should not need the quotes, nor the trailing /

Comment: Yes..I get the errors only when compiling the SensorNetworkUI project.

Comment: Ok you should try with "LIBS += -LC:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-dev/lib -llibqgis_core -llibqgis_gui" as these are not handled in the same way on Linux and Windows. Also the CORE_EXPORT & GUI_EXPORT may be source of the problem, even though yours seem correct

Comment: Nevermind for the "lib" prefix... not present here. Are your libraries compiled with the same compiler and architecture as your application ? Also present in your "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-dev/lib" directory (not the default one) as "qgis_core.dll" of course, even though it's obvious

Comment: Ok..I don't know how it happened..but I replaced __declspec(dllexport)
with __declspec(dllimport) and the number of build errors has now reduced..I still don't get where I am going wrong.

Comment: Great well done. Actually failed to notice this detail even though I saw the correct code. This is probably due to the way the macro is used in the code, but without digging into in that would be it. I'm editing my answer for future users by the way, if you want to include the solution in your question too

Comment: Thanks for all your help :)